# CodeIgniter CSS File Not Included

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter-url

I have a bit of an odd problem with my CodeIgniter installation, I am using modrewrite in order to shorten my URLs, for example I have an api page:

> http://www.mydomain.com/api

And it works really well, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But whats really strange is if I type a trailing slash:

> http://www.mydomain.com/api/

The API page loads ok but it doesn't include the Base CSS file which is included on all the pages, it would be fine if it didn't load anything at all, but I need to stop it from loading the actual api page. Any advice would be helpful,

Thanks!

UPDATE: I have found that when I view source my CSS file comes from the following when the CSS loads correctly:

> http://www.mydomain.com/css/all.css

But when it fails to load it comes from

> http://www.mydomain.com/api/css/all.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have a trailing slash in your `base_url` in the `config.php` file:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.mydomain.com/";
```

And always call the `base_url()` when dealing with links...etc

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/all.css">
```

EDIT:
Please note that I'm using the `mod_rewrite` from this [wiki page](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) BUT since my CI installation in not on the root (inside `/ci173/`) the `RewriteBase` is not `/` but `/ci173/`.

Answer (score 1):

When using relative URL path like `css/all.css` or `./css/all.css` (both are equivalent), you need to be aware that [relative URL paths (like any relative URLs) are resolved using a base URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) that is the URL of the current document if not specified otherwise.

So in your case `/api` or `/api/` is the base URL path and the relative URL path `css/all.css` is resolved differently depending on the base URL path:

- `/api` + `css/all.css` → `/css/all.css`
- `/api/` + `css/all.css` → `/api/css/all.css`

To conquer this you either need to

- use absolute URL paths like `/css/all.css` that are independent from the base URL path
- [specify a different base URL in your HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) (e.g. `/`); but note that this will affect *all* relative URLs and not just relative URL paths
- adjust your relative URL paths to suite your base URL paths:

  - for `/api` use `css/all.css`
  - for `/api/` use `../css/all.css`
  - for `/api/foo/bar/` use `../../../css/all.css`, etc.

I guess the first solution is the easiest.